# Why does click event give mismatch error?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am creating a calendar form and have the following code.

Without the `cmbMonth` and `cmbYear` click events the form load and displays the current date on the form.

When I add the click events it give me:

> Type mismatch error

on `first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & CInt(Me.cmbMonth.Value) & "-" & Me.cmbYear.Value)`.

Code from [www.PK-AnExcelExpert.com](https://www.PK-AnExcelExpert.com).

```vb
Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()
    If Me.cmbMonth.Value <> "" & Me.cmbYear.Value <> "" Then        
        lblMonthName.Caption = cmbMonth.Value
        Call Show_Date
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub cmbYear_Change()
    If Me.cmbMonth.Value <> "" & Me.cmbYear.Value <> "" Then                           
        lblMonthName.Caption = cmbMonth.Value          
        Call Show_Date         
    End If
End Sub
    
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
          
    With Me.cmbMonth
        For i = 1 To 12
            .AddItem VBA.Format(VBA.DateSerial(2019, i, 1), "MMMM")
        Next i
        .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "MMMM")
    End With

    With Me.cmbYear
        For i = VBA.Year(Date) - 12 To VBA.Year(Date) + 12
            .AddItem i
        Next i
        .Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "YYYY")
    End With
    Call Show_Date
End Sub
    
Sub Show_Date()
    Dim first_date As Date
    Dim last_date As Date
    first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & CInt(Me.cmbMonth.Value) & "-" & Me.cmbYear.Value)
    last_date = VBA.DateSerial(Year(first_date), Month(first_date + 1), 1) - 1
          
    MsgBox (first_date)
    MsgBox (last_date)
          
    '===To remove any caption from the date-buttons
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton
          
    For i = 1 To 42
        Set btn = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i)
        btn.Caption = ""
    Next i
               
    '===first date of the month
    For i = 1 To 7
        Set btn = Me.Controls("CommandButton" & i)
        If VBA.Weekday(first_date) = i Then
            btn.Caption = "1"
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that the YEAR list has nothing in it when the UserForm is initiated. These two `If` comparisons are the reason: `If Me.cmbMonth.Value <> "" & Me.cmbYear.Value <> "" Then` The `&` *concatenates text*, it does not perform the operator `AND` functionality. What you want is `If Me.cmbMonth.Value <> "" AND Me.cmbYear.Value <> "" Then`

Comment: @waris - it's best practice on SO to accept the answers that work for you or you find useful (by ticking the hollow green checkmark just underneath the voting buttons, near the top of this answer), 
so that others can benefit going forward :-)

Comment: Thanks Cindy. I made it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: use all parts in CDate argument as string type, as below:

```
first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & CStr(Me.cmbMonth.Value) & "-" & CStr(Me.cmbYear.Value))
```

Comment: Add Debug.Print Me.cmbMonth.Value , Me.cmbYear.Value above error line and then check the values they are in proper range. Maybe month is <1 or >12 or Year is wrong.

Comment: Hi: Barneyos. I followed your suggestion. It still gives me the same error message. The point is that it happens when I include the click/change event for cmbMonth and cmbYear. Otherwise form loads fine and month and year are displayed fine.

Comment: Please show what previous two Debug.print lines return. And what returns the line Debug.Print "1-" & CStr(Me.cmbMonth.Value) & "-" & Me.cmbYear.Value. The results You can see in Immediate Window (Ctrl-G) in VBA Editor.

Comment: Hi Barneyos: I put this commond before the error line and after but the program alsways gets the same message and flag is on ;

Comment: the same line: first_date = VBA.CDate("1-" & Me.cmbMonth.Value & "-" & Me.cmbYear.Value)

Answer (score 0):

What about using `DateSerial` and applying the `Month()` function based on regional settings as it *understands* the combobox formatted via local month names:

```
      first_date = VBA.DateSerial(Val(Me.cmbYear), Month("1-" & Me.cmbMonth), 1)
```